# Reference Request for a book on Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, book-recommendation

Please recommend me a book on Field theory which has **in-depth proofs** and **intuition** would by a plus point. Lately i've been having a hard time with it. Thanks. :)

I've tried Basic Algebra by P.M. Cohn and Topics in Algebra by I.N. Herstein, but I'm not very comfortable with them.

*Topics*

$1)$ Field Extensions

$2)$ Splitting Fields

$3)$ Normal fields and Normal Closure

$4)$ Automorphisms in field.

I cannot recall more. :)

Comment: basic algebra 1 and basic algebra 2 of jacobson are nice.

Comment: @Lolman thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Thomas W. Hungerford's algebra. Has helped me very much.

Answer (score 8):

You could try Milne's [Fields and Galois Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html), available for free on his website. It seemed relatively thorough last time I skimmed it.

Comment: Thank you! This website is amazing,l like it!