# Reference request for introductory Field Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory, book-recommendation

I am looking for books, notes, video lectures and other resources that cover the following topics in Field Theory and Galois Theory (taken from Basic Algebra: Groups, Rings and Fields by P. M. Cohn.):

Field Theory

7.1 Fields and their Extensions

7.2 Splitting Fields

7.3 The Algebraic Closure of a Field

7.4 Separability

7.5 Automorphisms of Field Extensions

7.6 The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory

7.7 Roots of Unity

7.8 Finite Fields

7.9 Primitive Elements; Norm and Trace

7.10 Galois Theory of Equations

7.11 The Solution of Equations by Radicals

Cohn itself is a bit too dense for me, so I'm looking for something more introductory with proofs of even the "obvious" results that are skipped there and more solved examples.

Related: [Reference Request for a book on Field Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979455/reference-request-for-a-book-on-field-theory)

Comment: What you mentioned is hard to follow at first (many definitions and theorems need to be accepted without proof) but once the main concepts are clear proving everything is not difficult, most books continue with the ring of integers (algebraic number theory) which are much more complicated.

Comment: There are enough recommendations on the site already to keep you busy for a long time.